# Geometric meaning of Koszul modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, algebraic-curves, syzygies

Assume $C$ is a smooth projective curve and $L$ is a line bundle on it. We say $L$ is $p$-very ample if for any effective divisor $D$ of degree $p+1$, the evaluation map $H^0(C,L)\to H^0(C,L\otimes\mathcal{O}_D)$ is surjective. Kemeny wrote in his paper "[The extremal secant conjecture for curves of arbitrary gonality](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/extremal-secant-conjecture-for-curves-of-arbitrary-gonality/7D607CAB936DCA8CFD54614075D9BB80)" that it is "rather straightforward" that if $L$ is not $p+1$-very ample then the Koszul cohomology $K_{p,2}(C;L)\not=0$. But I cannot see this, at least from the algebraic definition of the Koszul cohomology.

Is there any geometric explanation for Koszul cohomology, in which $p+1$-very ampleness might be involved?

Comment: You will have to do some digging yourself, but there is a paper of Green and Lazarsfeld in which they show how to construct non-zero Koszul cohomology classes from points in special position w.r.t a line bundle.  'not p+1 very ample' means that there are p+1 points in special position relative to L.  The construction of the class is explicit and imho, geometric.  Happy hunting.

Comment: Hi ! This is a result from Koh-Stillman's paper "Linear Syzygies and Line Bundles on an Algebraic Curve", see Prop. 3.6. You can also look at Chapter 4.4 of Aprodu-Nagel's book "Koszul Cohomology and Algebraic Geometry", in particular Theorem 4.36.

Comment: @mkemeny But those propositions induce that $L$ does not satisfy $N_p$(in fact $N_{p-1}$ in my situation). This doesn't imply the nonvanishment of $K_{p,2}$, right?

Comment: These two conditions are basically the same in our setting, see the top of page 8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4164.pdf